# CTE inside a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is SQL Server capable of having a CTE inside a subquery? I have not seen it.

Started using Oracle and saw a developer use CTE inside a subquery. Is SQL Server capable of it? I'm testing it on my own but it doesn't work in SQL Server. Let me know if CTE works inside a subquery.

Thanks

Comment: Not in SQL Server.

Comment: No.  SQL Server does not allow nested CTEs.

Comment: You could move the CTE into a table-valued function and call it via a  CROSS APPLY

Comment: sorry truncated ...   or as the subquery or even as part of a JOIN.

Comment: PostgreSQL can nest CTEs as well, but I haven't seen it in SQL Server yet.